# CSS fluid design box not aligning correctly

Tags: css

Hi i am trying to create my first fluid responsive layout and i am having a little problem , on the right i have a container that is longer than the boxes beside it and so i am trying to fit a box in the gap, you can see here: http://www.security-vacancies.net/test/fluid_test.html I am trying to get the purple box up and along side the grey box but it keeps starting again on a new line.

Here is my code for the two boxes.

```
 #job_seach {
clear: none;
float: left;
margin-left: 2.0408%;
width: 28.5714%;
display: block;
background-color:#CCC;
 }
 #lates_jobs {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 40.3877%;
display: block;
background-color:#909;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated thanks.

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space left for the purple box to follow the grey box(along side the grey box), that's why its going to a new line. If you want it to follow you will have to make space for it. Try, decreasing size of other div's and of your purple box if you want to squeeze it in.

Comment: I don't want it to follow the grey box, i want it in the position it is now just up alongside the grey box

Comment: sorry yes and the uncoloured one next to it

Comment: Why not put both the blue and purple div inside another div and give that container div appropriate width and give purple div clear:both and appropriate margin.